# print a binary tree how to fix the build_balanced_bst function

Tags: python, binary-tree

```
def str_tree(atree,indent_char ='.',indent_delta=2):
    def str_tree_1(indent,atree):
        if atree == None:
            return ''
        else:
            answer = ''
            answer += str_tree_1(indent+indent_delta,atree.right)
            answer += indent*indent_char+str(atree.value)+'\n'
            answer += str_tree_1(indent+indent_delta,atree.left)
            return answer
    return str_tree_1(0,atree)

def build_balanced_bst(l):
    if len(l) == 0:
        return None

    else:
        mid = (len(l)-1)/2
        if mid >= 1:
            build_balanced_bst(l[:mid])
            build_balanced_bst(l[mid:])
        else:
            return
```

I am working on the build_balanced_bst(l), the build_balanced_bst(l) takes a list of unique values that are sorted in increasing order. calling build_ballanced_bst( list(irange(1,10)) returns a binary search tree of height 3 that would print as:

```
......10
....9
..8
......7
....6
5
......4
....3
..2
....1
```

the str_tree function is used to print what the build_balanced_bst() function returns. my str_tree function is correct, I cannot change it. I can only change the build_balanced_bst() function.

I used the middle value in the list as the root’s value. when I try to call the build_balanced_bst(l) in the below, it does not print anything.

```
l = list(irange(1,10))
t = build_balanced_bst(l)
print('Tree is\n',str_tree(t),sep='')
```

can someone help me to fix my  build_balanced_bst(l) function? many thanks.

Comment: What is the structure of your tree supposed to be like? Is there a `Node` class or something? (The `str_tree` seems to expect something with `left`, `right` and `value` attributes.) Your `build_balanced_bst` function doesn't return anything (which technically means it always returns `None`). It recurses on the list you give it, but it never actually does anything with the list's data.

Answer (score 0):

`str_tree()` doesn't do anything: It just defines a nested function and implicitly returns `None`.

As a start, you can have str_tree do *something*:

```
def str_tree(atree, indent_char ='.', indent_delta=2):
    def str_tree_1(indent, atree):
        # Note that str_tree_1 doesn't use the indent argument
        if atree == None:
            return ''
    return str_tree_1(indent_delta, atree)
```

But this is just a start.